# Trying to get property of non-object error appears when my users try logging into thieir dashboard

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

```
         <div class="container-fluid">
          <h2 class="no-margin-bottom">Dashboard</h2>
        </div>
      </header>
    <?php
       AccusedCaseView($user_id);
       $TheBalance = DB::table('bank')->where('userid', $user_id)->first();
       if ($TheBalance->balance > "2000")
       {
         recomitmentWithdraw($user_id);
```

this is the code giving me that error..It pops up whenever my users try logging in to their dashboard

Comment: so the `$TheBalance->balance > "2000"` part is causing the error?

Comment: Yes..that is the part

Comment: Actually, that line is just the symptom of a larger problem. The underlying problem is that you don’t have an object being returned from DB::table. So to fix the issue, you need to find out why it’s not returning an object.  Once you get that fixed, you need to correct your error reporting on production so that you get an error log and the customer doesn’t see programming errors...

Comment: How do I do that..

Comment: Same way you debug anything— you can start at what doesn’t work and work your way back to where it does work, or start where it works and work your way to where it doesn’t.  That means you need to dig in to the db object and find what isn’t right.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some users have no bank records so in this case, you need to add this

```
if ($TheBalance->exists && $TheBalance->balance > "2000")`
```

Comment: what would `$TheBalance->exists` be if `$TheBalance` isn't an object?

Comment: if the object does not exist it will return false, so no deduction

Comment: if `$TheBalance` isn't an object then `$TheBalance->exists` would cause the same error because it isn't an object, and what would this `exists` property be if that was an object?

Comment: just to confirm the error is on this line : If ($TheBalance->balance > "2000") ??

Comment: Yes..that exact line

Comment: instead of exists can you try if( $TheBalance- !== null && $TheBalance->balance > "2000")

Comment: There is no other explanation !!